# Datagridview C# doesnt save data

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

Just trying out DataGrdview for the first time..

I have placed a datagridview in my win form , which gets data from an sql db.. while placing the datagridview, i had checked the enable adding,editing,and deleting options.

when i double click a cell in the grdview, i am able to edit it. but it doesnt seem to be saving the edited value.. same stuff happens while adding of deleting.

my code is this :

```
private void getgriddata() 
    {

        try
        {
            a = new SqlConnection(str);
            a.Open();
            b = new SqlCommand();
            b.Connection = a;
            b.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            b.CommandText="select * from maasti where Name   ='"+name_list.SelectedValue+"'";

            c = new SqlDataAdapter(b);
            d= new DataTable();
            c.Fill(d);

            grd_data.DataSource = d;


        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: grd_dta.Databind();. add this after assigning datasource

Comment: Explore events of datagridview. @Partha, OP referring to winforms.

Answer (score 0):

the grid doesn't save automatically ... you have to call Update on the dataadapter to save your changes ... also you have to create a Update-/Insert-/DeleteCommand for the SqlDataAdapter before you can call Update